# Changing 'name' property of jquery object

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having an issue with a Javascript object. When I use `push` on the object, both parts should take on the value of a variable. For some reason though, only `valueOfName` seems to change based on the variable. I need `name` to change as well, at the moment it seems to take whatever value it is written as with or without quotes. Here is the relevent code.

```
var obj = {};
obj.videoID = [];
var terms = ['best','awesome','incredible','insane','great'];
$.each(terms, function(cur, val){
    $.each(data.items, function(i, object) {
        $.each(object.id, function(property, value) {
            obj.videoID.push({val:value});
        });
    });
});
```

Am I going about this wrong? Or is there something I've missed? Thanks in advance for your help guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a object and use [Bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors#Bracket_notation) to create property with dynamic name, afterwards `push()` the object to array.

```
$.each(object.id, function(property, value) {
    var dummy = {}; //Create object
    dummy[val] = value; //create property and set value
    obj.videoID.push(dummy);
});
```